# Chrome local storage ignores .then() and .catch()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I trying to make a language manager for my chrome extension, for that I need to store an int value  in the local storage using a getter/setter.

```
function setLanguage(language) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({"language": language})
  .then(() => {
    //actions
    return (0);
  }).catch(() => {
    return (1)
  });
}

function getLanguage() {
  console.log("gettingLanguage");
  chrome.storage.local.get(["language"])
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.language);
    return (result.language);
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log("error");
    return (-1);
  });
  console.log("ignored");
}
```

When I use these functions in the same file, I get the correct output.
However upon calling the get function in antoher file, it seems to be ignoring the then and catch and somehow reaches the end of the function as shown below.

[image]

As I've said, I tried to put the calling function in the same file, however it causes more problems for the implementation of other features.

I try to search for other solutions online but didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: How are you using the `getLanguage` function in another file?

Comment: This is the correct behavior of asynchronous JS. Rework your code that calls getLanguage and chrome.storage.local.xxx and other asynchronous functions to use `async` + `await` syntax.

Comment: Remember also that chrome.storage get and set return a promise only in MV3.